# How do I find an element for this HTML code for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, robotframework

[image]

How do I find locator for a search box from this HTML code? I tried all the possible ways but no luck.

Comment: Can you share some code where you are unable to proceed?

Comment: Please do not post the HTML as image post it as formatted text so community members will be able to copy it possibly into an xpath tester tool or other.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options:

```
XPath = "//input[@placeholder='Enter a question']"
CSS = "[type='search']"
ID = "rc_select_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  input.ant-input.ant-input-lg[placeholder='Enter aquestion']
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  //input[@class='ant-input ant-input-lg' and @placeholder='Enter aquestion']
  ```